# Which records will be downloaded when CKFetchRecordChangesOperation will called with nil token?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckfetchrecordchangesopera

Will `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` retrieve all records from container?

I hoped it will download all my records, since I added many to different record types, but I get no one. I've initialised it with nil token.

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKFetchRecordChangesOperation_class/index.html) says: *A CKFetchRecordChangesOperation object reports on the changed and deleted records in the specified record zone. Use this type of operation object to optimize fetch operations for locally managed sets of records. Specifically, use it when you maintain a local cache of your record data and need to synchronize that cache periodically with the server.*

I even runned `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` from different device to exclude the case only changes performed on other devices is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKFetchRecordChangesOperation has nothing to do with CKSubscription. Instead it will just return all the changes to all recordTypes.

The documentation says this about the change token:

> The change token from a previous fetch operation. This is the token
>   passed to your fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock handler during a
>   previous fetch operation. Use this token to limit the returned data to
>   only those changes that have occurred since you last made the same
>   fetch request. If you specify nil for this parameter, the operation
>   object fetches all records and their contents.

So you will just get all the records.

Comment: Fortunately for you the documentations almost says the same about the change token for that :-) It says: The change token from a previous fetch operation, or nil to fetch all changes. When you specify a change token, the operation object fetches only the changes that occurred since the change token was generated.

Comment: Ah... but you are right... I think it will be the changes since the CKSubscription is created... hmmm let me look at that...

Comment: The documentation also says: 'retrieves unread CKNotification objects from a container.' So without a CKSubscription you won't have a CKNotification. So I think you will only get the changes since the CKSubscription is created... You need to investigate this to be sure.

Comment: **(1)** `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` works in public container too **(2)** with nil parameter it will not download all the notifications, just from the creation of the `CKSubscription` **(3)** my option is that in CloudKit `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is the most worthy method at all, this is like `NSFetchedResultedController` in `UITableView`, it implements the observer pattern in server - client communication